# What would be the Spanish equivalent of noreply@emailaddress.com?

Tags: coloquialismos, vocabulario-técnico, email

As a software developer, I've always wondered whether it was universal to use noreply@something.com for every language when sending emails to denote that an email reply would get no response, or whether different languages would need a different response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep using **noreply** because it will be understandable for everyone.

Maybe there is still a minority of people who are not too attached to technology and they won't realize or understand that (at least in Latin America people who is old and work with computers everyday) .

Even if you are building an application that supports i18n (internationalization) and i10n (localization) concepts, this is not important.
Nevertheless, you can use as user9138 said **noresponder@emailaddress.com** Also you can use **no-responder**, **mensaje-automatico**. There is no standard in that, even in English, in my humble opinion.

As a best practice, it is strongly recommended to use an email address that is relevant to the content that you are going to send. **services**@emailaddress.com, **helpdesk**@emailaddress.com, **support**@emailaddress.com, **sales**@emailaddress.com, etc. This is very important not only for Marketing, because some ISPs filters could manage your emails as a spam.

My advice is to include, in a visible part of your notification, a disclaimer stating that your email is not intended to be answered. This text can be localized/translated in many languages and the user will be more concerned about content and the intention of your email.

Answer (score 3):

"noresponder@emailadress.com" is commonly used, but I don't see any problem in leaving the address as it is